# WYSIWYG ACF Field seems to take on css styles from surrounding div

Tags: css, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I have a weird CSS styling issue with the WYSIWYG field. It seems this field never takes on the styling of the element where I add the field to but instead takes on the styling from the surrounding div. As an example: If I have a div and inside that div a p element, like this:

```
<div class=“div”>
        <p class="paragraph"><?php the_field('wysiwyg field’); ?></p>
</div>
```

Then the ACF field completely ignores the CSS style from the p element but takes on the CSS classes from the surrounding div element. Is that normal? I don’t have that issue with ACF text or text area fields.

So far, I just applied the styling I needed (like font size, font type, etc) to the div to make everything look like I needed but now I have another issue. The P element is supposed to have a margin-left and right of 100px. When I apply the WYSIWYG field to the p element, it completely ignores the margins styling though. So I thought to just apply the margins to the div element, but this creates a “double margin” since the div will have 100 px margin and additionally now the p element as well since the WYSIWYG field takes on the CSS styling from the surrounding div.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your wysiwyg field is probably generating paragraph tags on its own, and since you can't have <p> inside of <p>, then you probably just end up with an empty <p> tag above your wysiwyg content. Style the div insted and remove the surrounding <p> tag

Comment: thanks so much for the answer! The issue was actually somewhere else (and kinda stupid on my part). I had copied the text directly over from my Webflow site and since the padding was applied to the p element, it copied the margin over as well haha so just removing the margin from the p element, and adding it to the div and copying over the unformatted text was what was needed